# Dart/Flutter Blowfish CBC

Tags: dart, flutter, blowfish, cbc-mode

How to do Blowfish CBC decryption in Flutter/Dart? I can't find any libraries that support it.

`dbcrypt` supports only password hashing and no cbc mode.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

    final plainText = 'some plain text here';
    final key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8('16 characters key');
    final iv = IV.fromLength(16);
    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key,mode: AESMode.cbc,padding: 'PKCS7'));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
    final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);
    print(decrypted); 
    print(encrypted.base64);
```

pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
dependencies:

  encrypt: ^4.0.0
```

Comment: I don't know if works, I asked it 11 months ago, no need for it now.